# How do I specify a jquerymobile data-theme in a rails radio_button_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to set the JQueryMobile data-theme in a radio_button tag and, for some reason, I cannot get it to work properly. When I use:

```
<%= radio_button_tag :used_group_projects, "yes", { 'data-theme' => 'b' } %>
```

The resultant radio button is checked (which it should not be), but does not have a `data-theme="b"` but instead looks like this:

```
<input checked="checked" id="used_group_projects_yes" name="used_group_projects" type="radio" value="yes" />
```

On the other hand, the following (inside a `form_for`) produces the desired effect:

```
<%= f.radio_button :plausible, true, { 'data-theme' => 'b' } %>
```

As near as I can tell, the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) indicates that this should work, but it is not. Any ideas on how I might make this work?

Comment: I believe you need to do `<%= radio_button_tag :used_group_projects, "yes", data: { theme: 'b' } %>`

Comment: Yeah, @CWitty I tried that because I remembered having done something similar in the past, but for some reason, on the `radio_button_tag`, it only seems to result in the button showing up as `checked`.

Comment: Oh whoops the third option is checked which that is resulting in it being set to true you need to do `<%= radio_button_tag :used_group_projects, "yes", false, 'data-theme' => 'b' %>` where the `false` is whether you want it checked or not. Docs are found here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

Comment: @CWitty, this last was the trick - I'd just missed the parameter. I am wondering why you haven't posted this as the answer? I would really like to credit you with the correct response.

Comment: I appreciate it. I will post it shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do as follows: `<%= radio_button_tag :used_group_projects, "yes", false, 'data-theme' => 'b' %>`. Where the false is if you want it checked or not. Reposting from my comment above.